# In Struts 2, how do I access "fieldErrors" outside of an action?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am developing a website using Struts 2. Now, I am writing an Interceptor by extending AbstractInterceptor.

I want to access fieldErrors in the interceptor, but I don't know how to do it.
In an action which extends ActionSupport, I can add a field error just like this:

```
addFieldError(fieldName, errorMsg);
```

How to do the same thing in a customized interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way, by accessing the action's fieldErrors property, after casting the action to either ActionSupport, or the specific interface if you're not using ActionSupport.